# Composer/Laravel...[ERROS]

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer

Olá,estou com um sistema em php para dar manuntenção...só que eu queria subir a aplicação para fazer os testes e não estou conseguindo,procurei na net fiz algumas coisas, e mesmo assim me deparo com este erro no meu cmd ... na pasta onde estar o projeto.. estes erros é quando eu digito o comando **composer install**  como é tudo novo apartir daew não sei mais o que fazer..

Ativei tbm o meu extension=php_openssl.dll ,no php.ini 
pensando que poderia ser algo relacionado...agora eu não criei nenhum virtual host... ta o padrão do xampp 127.0.0.1 localhost

Estes erros me impedem de rodar a aplicação para programar e fazer algumas implementações..
I dont know my friends

tela dos erros são 27 :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você deve instalar a versão mínima do *PHP* que é a versão `5.6.4`

Comment: PHP Version 7.0.23 versão do meu php instalado..através do phpinfo();  já tinha observado isso faz tempo ..acredito que não seja isso deve ser algum tipo de permissão sei lá

Comment: Deve ter outra versão sendo executada, porque esta dizendo que a versão que você esta utilizando é a `5.5.8`

Comment: e como faço pra encontrar esta versão?? sendo que a ativa do xampp é a versão 7...

Comment: após eliminar os erros este projeto que eu clonei ele sobe ?? ou tem outra pasta que tenho que alterar??..eu não criei este projeto

Comment: Não, é só a questão de não estar rodando a versão mínima. Agora o servidor tem que ter no mínimo a versão `5.6.4` para funcionar

Comment: eu expliquei errado eu falo em subir tipo,pra eu alterar e implementar alguma coisa e rodar...tipo eu coloquei php artisan serve ...surge a mensagem que parece que aconteceu algo errado... estou pesquisando na net pra ver como rodar ele em minha máquina

Comment: [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/248231/edit) a pergunta e apenas coloca o novo erro.

Answer (score 0):

Tinha uma versão do easyphp .. que não sei a onde estava na minha máquina,após eu ter desinstalado o xampp e excluído os .exe dos easyphp consegui instalar novamente o xampp e com a versão que já tinha .. a 7 foi que os erros sumiram.

E para fazer a aplicação rodar em minha máquina, fui na pasta raiz do projeto onde tinha um arquivo chamado .env.example e renomei para .env e depois rodei o comando *php artisan key:generate*  Aew retornou a mensagem de sucesso e depois rodei novamente com php artisan serve .